# How to interpret the model number of a computer?

Tags: laptop

I am looking at computers online. To give an example, I see model numbers such as: "UX303LA-DS52T", "UX303LA-US51T", etc. But when I google "UX303LA-DS52T datasheet" to obtain the official datasheet of the product, all I get is the [webpage](https://www.asus.com/us/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_ZENBOOK_UX303LA/specifications/) for "UX303LA" in Asus' website. Now as far as I can tell, both of these models are different from each other, albeit with slight differences. So why can't I reach to specifications of a model such as "UX303LA-US51T" is Asus' website but only reach to specifications of "UX303LA"? How should I interpret the part of the model number that comes after "UX303LA"?

**Edit:** The reason I am asking this question is, although usually there are specifications for a product in a retailer's website, sometimes they are not complete. And sometimes they don't have specs at all. Furthermore, retailers act in a "no responsibility" manner. They claim that the information there is for the convenience of the customer only and the info there may be outdated/false. Hence, I feel like I should behave like the info on retailers' website is unreliable and hence, I should get the correct information from the manufacturer's website.

**Extra:** Is a similar concept present in other types of products as well? If so, how should I interpret them?

Comment: Most times slight changes to a model number indicate a hardware difference and/or indicates what region it was sold in.  As for what specific models names for a specific product mean, we can't tell you that, because we didn't manufacture the product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most products have different versions, weather they are revisions, region specific, different colors, etc.

They are used by manufacturers and retailers to make sure they deliver what you paid for.

There are no general rules (for this specific mark) and every manufacturer has their own way of marking models. So to a consumer they don't mean much and usually they don't make sense either, as in your example.

The best way to identify the different configurations is by their specifications listed on the retailer/manufacturer site or in store.

If they lack in detail, contacting a distributor or a big retailer and requesting a spread sheet for the specific model might be the way to go.

After a little digging, the US51T and DS52T differ in screen resolution and CPU.

Asus has this comparison table for their motherboards but not for laptops.

Comment: The problem is, retailers act in a "no responsibility" manner. They claim that the specs present on their website may be wrong/outdated. Furthermore, sometimes they sometimes omit some or all specs. That's why I feel like the information on the retailer website is unreliable and hence, I have to get the correct information from the manufacturer's website.

Comment: @Utku I understand your concern and it is a valid one. I had the same experience with some retailers, I was even sold the wrong unit once. Now, before I make a purchase I always call the distributor and ask for a spec list for every model config they have. Usually distributors have 1-2 models, sometimes even more. There are manufacturers that have a details for every model.

Comment: Just a note: I find one seller that asserts [US51T](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1164196-REG/asus_ux303la_us51t_i5_5200u_8gb_256gb_windows_8_1_13_3.html) can have i5 and i7, and [DS52T](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1141317-REG/asus_ux303la_ds52t_i5_5200u_8gb_256ssd_windows_8_1_13_3_touch.html) only the i5. To be checked of course. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to know that the extension on the model number represents various versions of that base model.

Generally those numbers are the [SKU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_keeping_unit) numbers, so that the different variations of the model (hardware, software, country of sale, etc.) will have different, identifiable #'s to go by when stocking for sale.

The manufacturers generally don't report detailed SKU info to the public (outside of when they sell them directly) as there are usually many of them, they don't mean much to an end-user, and they can/will change practically at random (parts shortages, new model variations, retired variations, etc.).

Check with an authorized reseller of the product to get specifics on which SKU represents which variation.

Comment: So there isn't a way to find the _official_ specifications of a particular product (model number + SKU)? I am asking this because some websites does not include some/all specs and furthermore, they say that the info there is not official and hence, may be outdated/wrong.

Comment: @Utku - Contact the manufacture for specific questions about your product.  They can supply the relevant specifications of your device easily enough, they produced it, so if it exists they have it.

Comment: @Ramhound They must have it but not in an easily accessible manner in this case, right? Isn't not putting the information on their website kind of impractical? Why do they behave in this way?

Comment: @Utku - How should I know?  If you want the specifications of your laptop, contact the manufacture, every manufacture handles different models, SKUs, and regional products differently.

Comment: @Utku "So there isn't a way to find the official specifications of a particular product (model number + SKU)?"  Yes, contact a representative of the manufacturer, and/or an authorized reseller directly. Web site content often goes out of date, hence why they have disclaimers saying they are not authoritative. :)

Answer (score 2):

On a side in the seller's world it is needed to have one unique ID for each couple of model and price: you need to control how much you pay your item and which will be the selling price.
The world of computer producers creates *"trillion"* of variants. If the producer will not give one subcode, the seller will create one [SKU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_keeping_unit). Often they will add their one even if one subcode just exists, and for this you will never find in the producer web site.

The marketing guys are worried that normal people will be scared if the model is too long and they press to have short names, easy to be remembered maybe with some fashion name (Zenbook) to inspire.

On the other side some clients would like to have the possibility to do comparison and to identify *quickly* the model, maybe not for the internal components but for shape and general class (in your example UX303LA)...

It's almost a general schema, for Asus is a not new problem, and from past you take hints when official documentation misses:

- [Apr 2, 2006 "The Official ASUS Model Number Explination"](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/the-official-asus-model-number-explination.47570/)
- [Feb 14, 2011 "ASUS Notebook Brand Models Explained"](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/asus-notebook-brand-models-explained.555093/)
- [Sep 05, 2012 "ASUS model codes… please explain"](http://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?14337-ASUS-model-codes%85-please-explain)
- and you can bet that the list will grow and grow in time...